# Translation Golf XXXVI - Everybody do the Translation Golf!

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> Everybody dance when Walen translate
>   He won this game!

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

At this time, to continue the *comics line*, i'm gonna propose this song from 'One froggy evening' with a song written for this comic, that you can hear [here](https://soundcloud.com/tom-sandman-1/michigan-rag)

The version to translate is these:

> Everybody do the Michigan Rag
>   Everybody likes the Michigan Rag
>   Every Mame and Jane and Ruth
>   From Weehawken to Duluth
>   Stomp, romp, pomp the Michigan
>   Jump, clump, pump the Michigan Rag
>   That lovin' rag!
>
> <sub>(160 characters.)</sub>

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here's a (non-golfed) example translation:

> Todo el mundo hace el *Michigan Rag*
>  A Todo el mundo le fascina el *Michigan Rag*
>  A todas, a Jane, a Mame y a Ruth
>  Desde Weehawken hasta Duluth
>  Contonea, zarandea y pisotea en el *Michigan*
>  Respinga, estruja y zapatea en el *Michigan Rag*
>  ¡Que hermoso el *rag*!
>  <sub>(195 characters)</sub>

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: ¿Hay que mantener los versos?

Comment: @blonfu será lo ideal, mantengamos los versos

Comment: Cuando hice la pregunta no había ninguna traducción. Justo @walen puso la suya casi en el mismo momento, luego ya más tarde Charlie. No quisiera que cambiaran las reglas por mi comentario una vez empezado el juego, además si el verso es libre acaba siendo una prosa con saltos de línea como ya pasó una vez y no le veo mucho sentido

Comment: después de comentarlo con la almohada, lo mejor es mantener las respuestas que se han dado, "prosificando" las respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 28

> ¡Bailad Michigan Rag, a todos gusta!

Comment: Pero... qué... cómo... eeh. Me voy a mi casa

Comment: (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻ _(leaves the site...)_

Comment: seré cruel, pero ante tu genialidad, mantengamos los versos @walen y por cierto (aunque vendrá una pregunta al respecto) tu versión diría Míchigan *Rag* (Rag es extranjerismo y Míchigan lleva tilde)

Comment: Bueno, pasado casi un día desde la publicación de esta respuesta, me gustaría solicitar al [respondedor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WCjAmjH) que argumente detalladamente en qué partes de su traducción se encuentra cada término del texto original.

Answer (score 3):

#### 38 caracteres, *walen style*

> ¡Saltad al son del *rag* de [Michigan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_J._Frog), todos lo aman!

Dejo aquí mi primer intento de traducción:

#### 102 caracteres

> Todos bailando el *rag* de Michigan,
>   a todos les gusta,
>   todas
>   por [doquier](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8yw125),
>   pisad, brincad, gritad,
>   saltad, trotad, dadle al *rag*,
>   ¡lo amo!

Aclaraciones:

- Lo importante en este caso no creo que sea respetar los nombres incluidos en la letra, más allá del nombre del propio *rag*, sino mantener las ideas presentadas (lo baila cualquier mujer, se baila en todas partes, etc.). Siguiendo esa idea, el verso *Every Mame and Jane and Ruth* como habla de nombres de mujer se traduce simplemente por *todas*, y el siguiente verso habla de que se bailan en todas partes, así que se traduce por *por doquier*.
- El término *[rag](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragtime)* viene de *ragtime* o *ragged-time*, siendo *rag* la abreviatura. No tiene traducción al español, así que lo dejo como *rag* en cursiva.

Comment: El *rag* sería de Míchigan, con tilde, @Charlie

Comment: Michigan es un nombre propio, no lleva tilde. ¿El pato Donald lleva tilde?

Comment: @blonfu pues parece que VeAqui tiene razón, [el nombre castellanizado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%ADchigan) sí lleva tilde...

Comment: No exactamente: http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Acentuaci%C3%B3n#Nombres_propios

Comment: @blonfu ese párrafo habla sobre nombres propios, no sobre topónimos, que se tratan justo en el párrafo siguiente al que enlazas, y dice "los nombres geográficos que ya están acuñados en castellano o adaptados a su fonética ya no son tratados como extranjeros, por lo que se acentúan siguiendo las reglas generales". Según tu razonamiento entonces no deberíamos acentuar "París".

Comment: Correcto, pero es que Michigan en este caso es una rana de dibujos llamada [Michigan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_J._Frog) y no el estado de Míchigan

Comment: @blonfu ¡ouch! Jaque mate, habrá que dejarlo entonces sin tilde. :-D Pensaba que hablaba del _rag_ que se baila en el estado de Michigan (como el _Gangnam Style_, dado que _Gangnam_ es un barrio de Seúl). Ahora entiendo a qué viene tanto saltar y brincar en el texto original, tratándose de una rana... :-D